# SOQL query all private report "USING SCOPE allPrivate" not working in some environements

Tags: apex, soql

The following query is not working as mentioned in document, getting exception [object Object]: Invalid query scope: allPrivate

SELECT Id FROM Report USING SCOPE allPrivate WHERE LastRunDate < LAST_N_DAYS:365

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_api_soql.htm#rn_api_soql_allprivate

it works in some sandbox but not in others, all sandboxes are spring 16 or above with api version 36.0.  i also have manage private report permission.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's a permission issue, solved using the information below:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000232625&language=en_US

I forgot to enable folder sharing (Enable Analytics Sharing for the organization) as mentioned here, I just only enabled Manage Private reports and dashboard previously, thats why the error coming up.

Comment: Can you please add relevant information from the link to your answer? Links tend to break over time and become less useful.

Comment: I forgot to enable folder sharing (Enable Analytics Sharing for the organization) as mentioned here, I just only enabled Manage Private reports and dashboard previously, thats why the error coming up.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer with that information instead of leaving it in the comments.